# Custom Workflow Feature not available in Site Features or Site Collection Features

Tags: 2013, workflow, visual-studio-2012, solution-deployment, features

I have a Sequential Workflow created in Visual Studio.  In VS I can right click and deploy the package without issue. On the TEST environment I use the command add-spsolution and then deploy it to my web application through central administration.  No errors reported so far.

I cannot find the feature either in `Site Collection Features` nor `Site Features` to activate it - although it doesn't show up in either location on my DEV environment either.

I've checked the following:

1. Feature folder in the hive contains the same files
2. No errors reported on adding the solution
3. No errors reported on activating the solution
4. The `DLL` is correctly deployed to the bin folder
5. All lists the workflow depends on are present - as far as I am aware
6. No `XOML` files are present on my dev machine feature folder in the hive, same for the test machine
7. In DEV env I can click list settings > workflows > add a workflow and see my workflows, in the TEST env I can only see the default workflows.
8. Tried changing the feature scope away from `Site` scope (i.e. `Farm`, `WebApplication` and `Web`)  but in all instances a message was displayed saying that the Workflows could not be deployed in that scope, only `Site` scope works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you are looking for:

```
Install-SPFeature
```

It is needed to install every new feature if you deploy through powershell.

Steps required:

1. Add-SPSolution
2. Install-SPSolution
3. Install-SPFeature
4. Enable-SPFeature - for specific site col./web

More info about Install-SPFeature on msdn: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607825.aspx

Comment: doesnt clicking `Deploy Solution` from Central Administration install the feature? anyway `Get-SPFeature` shows the feature as being in the Web Application already.  Using Enable-SPFeature made my workflows available but I need to figure out why the feature isnt in `Site Collection Features`

Comment: By any chance...isn't feature hidden?

Comment: if it is - its not intentional.

Comment: You can check it by PS, this code displays all web scoped hidden features: Get-SPFeature -Limit ALL | Where-Object {$_.Hidden -eq $true -and $_.Scope -eq "WEB"} | Sort-Object DisplayName | Select DisplayName,Id

Comment: yeah, I found it that way and enabled it using the guid in Powershell with the `Enable-SPFeature` command.